# Is it a good idea to link your LinkedIn profile in the CV section of your dissertation?

Tags: career-path, cv, thesis

I've passed the disputation and am now preparing the document for the printing press and final submission. We're required to have a CV in the back matter of the dissertation, and I was wondering if it is a good idea to link to my LinkedIn profile in addition (perhaps with a QR code) because it'll be far more up to date than the CV in my dissertation.

Do you think this is a good idea? Are there any things I should consider when doing this?

Comment: _which will only be printed once_ — What is this "printed" of which you speak, earthling?

Comment: The dissertation will only be printed once. Updated for clarity. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question indicates that you want to use a link to your LinkedIn profile in your CV because "*it'll be far more up to date than the CV in my dissertation*." Are you suggesting that (a) you are going to include a CV that is not up to date, or that (b) your LinkedIn profile will be updated over time and that you won't be able to go back and edit your dissertation?

If you mean (a), then *no*, you need to keep your CV up to date and a link to an online profile will not work. Your academic CV should always be kept as up to date as possible and it should *absolutely* be updated before you submit it in an application or include it in a dissertation. If you are doing your CV correctly, it will include different information than a LinkedIn profile and there is a strong expectation that every academic will have one.

If you mean (b) and are just worried that an archival copy of your CV will be out of date, sure, add a link to LinkedIn or similar. My CV links prominently to my academic homepage on at a permanent (i.e., non-university) URL, which is kept up to date, and which includes a link to the latest version of my CV at all point. I include a date in the footer of my CV although folks will have a date in your dissertation. Personally, I think this is better than relying on a for-profit company and its URLs for posterity.

In terms of the QR code, I'd skip it. These days, almost everybody who reads the dissertation will read a soft copy. A hyperlink will be much more useful. I suspect that a QR code will just end up make the document look dated at some point in the rather near future.

Comment: And a LinkedIn profile won't look dated in near future? Just 10 years ago someone might have asked the same question about adding a link to their GeoCities page...

Comment: I agree completely. That's why I recommended against using it int he sentence before I recommended against QR codes. I could have done it more strongly.

Comment: I decidede to add a link to my personal website which at the moment forwards to my LinkedIn profile.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good idea, so long as it is not instead of a proper CV.

Just remember that links go out of date and QR codes will become outdated technology. So when LinkedIn goes out of business, the link and QR codes will be just be remnants of a time gone by.